# Exception while implementing sensor Listener with xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, sensors

I created a class which extends the inteface ISensorEventListener to get the values of sensors. Can you tell what I have to do in the following function related to the interface ISensorEventListener.

```
public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is an handle who is used in java, you can implement something specific but some times you just need to extend from this object to avoid this implementation :

```
  class YourClass: Java.Lang.Object, ISensorEventListener.
```